# How to add a new line in textarea element in php code?

Tags: php, textarea, line-breaks, contact-form-7

I want to add a newline in a textarea. I tried with < p> tag but it's not working. Can you help me to insert a newline in a textarea? Please find the code above for a generic contact form. Where should I add tags for line breaks here?

```
public function cs_form_textarea_render($params = '') {
    global $post, $pagenow;
    extract($params);
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
        $cs_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cs_' . $id, true);
    } else {
        $cs_value = $std;
    }
    if ( isset($cs_value) && $cs_value != '' ) {
        $value = $cs_value;
    } else {
        $value = $std;
    }
    $cs_rand_id = time();
    if ( isset($force_std) && $force_std == true ) {
        $value = $std;
    }
    $html_id = ' id="cs_' . sanitize_html_class($id) . '"';
    $html_name = ' name="cs_' . sanitize_html_class($id) . '"';
    if ( isset($array) && $array == true ) {
        $html_id = ' id="cs_' . sanitize_html_class($id) . $cs_rand_id . '"';
        $html_name = ' name="cs_' . sanitize_html_class($id) . '_array[]"';
    }
    $cs_required = '';
    if ( isset($required) && $required == 'yes' ) {
        $cs_required = ' required="required"';
    }
    $cs_output = '<div class="' . $classes . '">';
    $cs_output .= ' <textarea' . $cs_required . ' rows="5" cols="30"' . $html_id . $html_name . ' placeholder="' . $name . '">' . sanitize_text_field($value) . '</textarea>';
    $cs_output .= $this->cs_form_description($description);
    $cs_output .= '</div>';
    if ( isset($return) && $return == true ) {
        return force_balance_tags($cs_output);
    } else {
        echo force_balance_tags($cs_output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Globals inside a class method are a complete anathama to the concept of encapsulation, please inject those values instead

Comment: `extract($params);` also opens the door to another complete nightmare even if it is inside the scope of a method... Where DO all these parameters come from?? Who could possibly know, and when they dont exist, where were they supposed to come from

Comment: Hint: Textareas contain plain text, not HTML

Comment: And I hate to think what `sanitize_html_class()` does :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `"\n"` char somewhere between your text area tags

```
$cs_output .= ' <textarea' . $cs_required . ' rows="5" cols="30"' . $html_id . $html_name . ' placeholder="' . $name . '">' . sanitize_text_field($value) . "\n" . "this text is on a new line". '</textarea>';
```

Comment: What does not work ? it doesn't add a new line or it does not display the textarea at all ?

Answer (score 0):

You will try to add "\n"  before your end position of the tag. You need to concatenate Like ."\n".